# two registration forms in cakephp 2

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.0

Is there a way to have two registration forms in Cakephp 2? I have a registration form for Families and one of Jobseekers. Families are looking for a job seeker such as nannies or baby sitters. They can log in only to edit their name, address etc. Job seekers are those looking for a family to take care of and they can only log in to edit their profile. So obviously these two Models will connect because a Jobseeker can work with more than one Family. A Family can also have more than one Jobseeker.

If I use only one User table/model for storing both, it'll be pretty messy especially since a Jobseeker & FAmily may have some similar fields and different fields from each other. I'd like to have a User table (used for Families) and another table (Jobseeker table maybe?) that I can use for Jobseekers but also use the same login & registration functionalities as a User table.

Cakephp uses the Users table for their login mechanism and I'd like something similar to my JObseeker. I dont want to have to use the same table for two different types of users.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Just let users have only the user information (username, password, name, etc) and create two other tables for extra info job_seekers and families. Both tables will have a foreign_key to users (so JobSeeker and Family belongsTo User)

You can present the form using the extra fields with the Model.field notation (JobSeeker.education for example) and use saveAll() to store all data ata one including relationships.

Comment: Would they share the same controller (userscontroller)?

Comment: One controller can use more than one model. So if you do like Jose Lorenzo says, you can use in `UsersController` the `users` model as well as the two specific ones `job_seekers` and `families`. (linked to their respectives tables)